# how to show laser scanner data in rviz

Tags: rviz, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys
i'm beginner in ros i want to show 04lx laser scanner in rviz and i used this command
"roscore" "rosrun urg_node urge_node" "rosrun rviz rviz" but i can't see laser scanner
data how can i see the laser data? is need another command?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79281/how-to-show-laser-scanner-data-in-rviz/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2013-09-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [RViz documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz), its [Built-In Display Types](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes) and particularly [LaserScan](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/LaserScan) display type.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-23**:
tnx man :)

**Comment by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) on 2017-02-03**:
How is this the accepted answer?
If you arn't going to answer the question properly, THEN DON'T ANSWER IT!!!!!
People like you are why the learning curve for ros is a cliff. The documentation sucks, and telling people to go and read it instead of answering a simple question is why it's so steep.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2017-02-03**:
@Ben12345 If you read the suggested pages and still have questions, then ask them. (There is a button on the top right "Ask your question"). Also, I highly recommend to go through the [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) and [RViz User Guide](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After launching Rviz, I set /scan as topic in LaserScan  and set /laser as Fixed Frame in Global Options. Of course, I added LaserScan to Displays from default. I could see the laser data.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Gomez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12286/victor-gomez/) on 2014-08-18**:
For new people to ROS, this answer works fine. Make sure to change the Global Options. Nevertheless, reading the documentation will help you further away.

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-04-06**:
@Ken_in_JAPAN Does `/laser` refers to the laser link in urdf?

**Comment by [Deepak_Kr_Yadav](https://answers.ros.org/users/46827/deepak_kr_yadav/) on 2020-06-26**:
without laser link on actual URDF, still you can visualise /scan data by just mentioning laser at global option.

**Comment by [Benjamin Klaus](https://answers.ros.org/users/72121/benjamin-klaus/) on 2021-03-18**:
Since I've wasted way too much time for this simple task, here an additional hint:
If there is an error message like `For frame [base_scan]: Frame [base_scan] does not exist`, set the fixed frame in global options to exactly this name `base_scan`. Also see my answer here: https://answers.ros.org/question/59881/visualize-laserscan-usig-rviz/?answer=374231#post-id-374231